# UISearchController not displaying "no results" in background and how to alter dimmed background

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UISearchController` and the "No Results" is not showing during searches. How do I get this to appear in the UISearchController background when nothing is found? I would also like the search controller to behave like the `UISearchDisplayController` where the background dims when you click the searchBar initially, but undims when typing begins. I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For the "No Results" question, Daniel Amitay has a really good answer on another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4840621/4525245

For the dimming question, if I understand you right, you could just have a translucent image that adds over the UItableView after the searchBar is tapped and have it remove after the user taps the keyboard. Might not be elegant but it should work.